# How to import mongoose-encryption instead of using "require"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am using "type:" "module" in my package.json file and use "import" statements for all node packages rather than the require('packageName') syntax. But when I try to import mongoose-encryption like this:

```
import mongoose-encryption from 'mongoose-encryption';
```

...then, VS Code throws an error: 'import ... =' can only be used in TypeScript files. (ts 6133).

Mongoose-encryption is the only package giving me this error.

Help?

Comment: Did you try without `-` like `mongooseEncryption` ?

Comment: import * as mongooseEncryption from 'mongoose-encryption'

Answer (score -1):

```
import mongooseEncryption from "mongoose-encryption";
```

Comment: Please provide a more detailed and easier-to-understand explanation in your answer. Use the edit function to improve it. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).